# Stopping Percona version of MySQL from starting on boot

Tags: mysql, percona

I am having trouble keeping the Percona build of MySQL from starting on boot. With regular MySQL I was able to change /etc/init/mysql.conf and just comment out the start on lines, but this does not seem to be working with Percona. Anybody have similar issues?

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [sf] or [su]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --level 2345 mysql off
```

More info on run levels:

```
cat /etc/inittab
```

Comment: +1. I was going to reply "Don't edit init scripts! The OS provides a way to enable and disable services in various runlevels!"